# Assigning return values from api to state in React

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to call an api assign the returned values to a state object in React, the API is returning values but the values are not being set to state, not understanding what's the reason thank you

```
handleDDLCommunityChange = event => {
    let filesFromApi = []; // ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"];

    fetch('https://localhost:44352/api/files/Community-1')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            filesFromApi = data.map(file => { return { value: file, display: file } });
        }).catch(error => {                
            console.log(error);
            debugger;
        });
    console.log(filesFromApi);

    this.setState({
        files: filesFromApi.map(file => {
            return {
                fileName: file,
                checked: false
            };
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: `setState` should be inside the `then` function. Your API call happens asynchronously and it will be delayed a bit. You are calling your setState before your can API respond

Answer (score 0):

[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is an [async method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). An async method dispatches an action with the callbacks and unblocks following code branch from executing. The callbacks are then used to act on completion (success or failure) of the async method execution.

As you are calling the `setState` outside of the callbacks of the fetch call's chain, it's not guaranteed to run after the fetch call is done. As Sudheer has pointed out in their comment, you should try to set the state in a `then` block of the fetch chain.

**warning: untested code**

```
handleDDLCommunityChange = event => {
    let filesFromApi = []; // ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"];

    fetch('https://localhost:44352/api/files/Community-1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        filesFromApi = data.map(file => ({ value: file, display: file });
        this.setState({
            files: filesFromApi.map(file => ({
                fileName: file,
                checked: false
            })
        })
    });
    }).catch(error => {                
        console.log(error);
        debugger;
    });
};
```

Comment: I did the same but I am getting the following error, any help please? Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: I am getting the following error like here: response.json(...).map is not a function

Comment: @Abdul: updated my code. still, the code is untested.

Comment: I got it fixed my friend - thanks a lot, it was all different problem, I was calling different api - thanks again a lot.